# Remove the right margin of my class "row"

Tags: html, css

I want to set right padding for my first image and my sample menu for responsiveness but I want my second image's right padding not affected.

I tried to give my class "col" a padding-right of 20px and set the margin-right of my class "row" of -20px but it seems not working.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

```css
body {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.col {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 150%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.col img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.clearfix,
.row {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/practice1.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is just a demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is just a demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is just a demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is just a demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is just a demo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <p>This is just a demo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row images">
    <div class="col col-xs-6"><img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/7A715AD8-449D-4B5A-ABA2C5D92D9B5A21_source.png" alt="bird"></div>
    <div class="col col-xs-6"><img src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/7A715AD8-449D-4B5A-ABA2C5D92D9B5A21_source.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX9DX.png)

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem or helped in finding the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this whole thing in grid to be honest.

If you want your content to neatly fit in a grid, use grid. If you want your boxes to be aware of the size of your content, use flex-box.

However, you could just use a flexbox with space-between for the images class as a least amount of effort workaround:

```
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

*You should avoid using padding and margin to position your elements, especially negative values.*

Here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/H3AR7B3A7/uzrpkdyc/18/) as an example.

Comment: I fiddled some more to make it look a little better.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not part of your design, you might consider containing everything within a `border-box`. That way, the borders do not overflow.

Set

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Next, you can leverage specificity using the nth:child() selector. Since you need a 20px spacing between the two columns, you can set a 10px spacing at the right and left of the columns like this:

```
.row .col:nth-child(1){
  padding-right: 10px; // the first .col element in the row will have a right padding 
  }

.row .col:nth-child(2){
  padding-left: 10px; // the second .col element will have a left padding
  }
```

Check the updated version of your code on [this pen](https://codepen.io/somtoChukwun/pen/RwQBqYZ). Hope this helps.